# exec() command in python can't change global variables from inside function

Tags: python, function, exec, global

Title says everything I know

```
def fun():
    global v
    v = 1
    exec("global " + "k")
    exec("k" + " = 1")

fun()

print(v)
# prints 1
print(k)
# NameError: name 'k' is not defined
```

I expect the algorithm to print 1 both for v and for k but I get an error.

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on the context of this question?  It's not clear what your overall goal is and it's very likely there are better ways to achieve it than using global variables and `exec` statements.

Comment: Thank you Eliahu Aaron, this link helped me fix my issue.

Comment: Kyle Parsons, the question got answered by including globals() as a parameter to the exec function. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `globals()` to the `exec` function call:

```py
def fun():
    global v
    v = 1
    exec("k" + " = 1", globals())

fun()

print(v)
# prints 1
print(k)
# prints 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the exec you can assign the value of k like this

```py
def fun():
     exec("globals()['k'] = " + "1")

fun()

print(k) # output is 1
```